# ES6 iterators and @@iterator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

> In order to be iterable, an object must implement the @@iterator
>   method, meaning that the object (or one of the objects up its
>   prototype chain) must have a property with a Symbol.iterator key:

[Source](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:pIARVmEEsegJ:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk).

What does the `@@` prefix indicate here? Does this mean that iterables must have a method on their prototype chain with a name corresponding to the `Symbol.iterator` value?

Comment: *"Does this mean that iterables must have a method on their prototype chain with a name corresponding to the `Symbol.iterator` value?"*  They have to implement a property whose property name *is* the value of `Symbol.iterator`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes and I presume the corresponding property value must be a function object with a well defined API?

Comment: Yes. The function has to return an object that implements the iterator protocol, as explained in article you linked to (or I guess it's actually not that explicit).

Comment: I realized it's the same link you posted.